# SQLcomplete doesn't update after database was added

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've started using the SQLcomplete refactoring tool for SQL Server Management Studio. It appears that every time I add a new database to my instance it doesn't update the SQLcomplete tool with the new schema for that database.

Anybody know how to get around that so it works?

Comment: Restarting Management Studio probably works.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I would like to not have to do that every time I add new databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>? This refreshes the cached schema, and can be done any time there is a schema change--which includes adding new databases.